# Error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING" Happening only at remote servers

Tags: android, retrofit, restful-authentication, okhttp

I have this bug happening when accessing a login route from my restful api (Rails), but only for an specific address.

Here's the deal, I have 3 different addresses which I can use to test my Android Application. One is my local machine, I start my rest server locally for testing and dev purposes and as my build variant I choose dev which is pointed to my local machine.

Everything runs well for the login route. Here's a sample of my route (I'm using Retrofit):

```
 @POST("api/sessions")
 Call<User> login(@Body JsonElement user);
```

Also, here's my retrofit rest manager, just in case:

```
public static RestService getService(){

    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            return response;
        }
    });

    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL) //the URL comes from my BuildConfig
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    return client.create(RestService.class);
}

public static RestService getServiceWithHeaders(Context context){
    applicationContext = context;
    Response result = null;

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    session = new UserSessionManager(applicationContext);
    final User u = session.getUser();

    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okClient.interceptors().add(logging);
    okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            if (u.email != null) {
                Request original = chain.request();

                Request newRequest = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("X-User-Email", u.email)
                        .header("X-User-Token", u.authentication_token)
                        .method(original.method(), original.body())
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            } else {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                return response;
            }
        }
    });


    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okClient)
            .build();
    return client.create(RestService.class);
}
```

And at my LoginActivity, here's how I call it:

```
 User u = new User();
 u.email = String.valueOf(edit_text_email.getText());
 u.password = String.valueOf(edit_text_password.getText());

 RestService service = RestManager.getService();
 JsonElement jsonUser = u.toJson(); //my user
 Call<User> call = service.login(jsonUser);
 call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
         if (response.isSuccess()) {
             User user = response.body();

             user.password = u.password;
             user.save();


         } else {
             //some treatment routines        
         }
     }

     @Override
     Public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

         Log.e(TAG, "doLoginRoutines Failure: " + t.getMessage().toString());


     }
     });
```

So, before calling the login retrofit method, I transform my User object to a JsonElement, as requested from my route. Here's the output of it:

> {"user":{"email":"myEmail@gmail.com","password":"myPassword"}}

Like I said before, when accessing that routine from my local server, everything runs alright, but if I choose either way my staging server or my production server, it returns me this message:

> "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Now, all my three restful servers match, for I'm the only person working on these other 2 servers (staging and production), there's not a single different routine coming from these other 2 servers in that regard.

Now, I understand it's pointing to something wrong with my User JsonElement. Apparently, it should be an Object but a string's been passed. The thing is (as far as I understood it), my JsonElement is an Object and I've tried to tinker with that route, passing purely string, then an Object with no avail.

I'm lost!

BTW, here's my libs, in case that helps:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: What does the retrofit logging says? Do you get there also `{"user":{"email":"myEmail@gmail.com","password":"myPassword"}}`?

Comment: am expecting some thing not correct in you **User.class**, Also double conform your local server response and staging server response are same.

Comment: Add setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL) to your Retrofit.Buider() call and check request and response. Maybe you'll find an issue

Comment: Can you confirm that your staging or production server is returning an user object as your localhost does? It seems that they aren't returning an user object or it hasn't the same structure as your localhost user object.

Comment: You can use your own custom GsonConvertyFactory, Which extended converter.factory class.

Comment: Sorry for the delay...

Nothing is being rendered from the server side, as if it didn't even get there. The error seems to stay at the android app and never leaves.

I cannot set LogLevel to FULL, there's only this BODY or HEADER log. the best output I'm getting from Retrofit is this " doLoginRoutines Failure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" message.

It seems to me that I'm facing not some difference of environments, but a compatibility issue. But I'm uncertain up to this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found what was happening to the server. The error was actually happening somewhere else but being thrown at that point that I reported here.

For my staging and prod servers, we use https but that's not the case for my local server, so as I didn't setup the URL properly to contain the secure HTTP for staging and production servers, my okHTTP wasn't finding the rest route properly.

That's interesting to note that the error should have been logged as route not found instead of this one I was getting.